# Postgresql - truncate numbers to range

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, truncate

Is there a built-in function to truncate values of one type to fit the range of another type? E.g casting a `INTEGER` to `SMALLINT`. This might fail if the `INTEGER` is larger than `SMALLINT` can hold. I would like the number to be truncated to the largest possible `SMALLINT` in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My motivation does not change the nature of my question @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No inbuilt function I'm aware of, you would need to use a case expression to handle the min and max values e.g:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN your_integer_column > 32767 THEN 32767
    WHEN your_integer_column < -32768 THEN -32768
    ELSE your_integer_column
END::smallint AS truncated_smallint
FROM your_table;
```